# Are there any established solutions to creating unlocking keys for ISV solutions / customizations?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

We have several custom products build on Acumatica's framework - but don't know how to integrate them with Acumatica's licensing scenario - or if we can create our own unlocking key implementation that integrates with Acumatica.

Does anyone know of something like this that's been done?

Comment: I looked at the related questions. And it was you who asked the same question 6 years ago :)

Comment: Exactly.  It wasn't possible then.  I was putting out a probe to see if anything had changed.

Comment: Technically, you can generate unlocking keys based on the registered company name in the license file or installation ID. The issue with installation ID is that it most likely will change without any notice in advance if they do some maintenance to the server or move the system to another server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To integrate with Acumaticas licensing model both business and technical steps will need to be taken.

Within Acumatica you will need to develop a custom feature switch which requires modification of the `Features.xml` file as well as the extension of the `FeatureSet` DAC and table, documentaion for these steps can be found in the "Acumatica ERP Customization Guide", a version of which I have linked below.

"To Add a Custom Feature Switch"

https://www.acumatica.com/media/2020/02/AcumaticaERP_CustomizationGuide.pdf

Once the technical steps have been taken you will be required to submit your solution ( code and documentation ) to the Acumatica team for review and addition to their internal licensing server.

You may only submit to the Acumatica if you are a registered ISV Partner. The current link to begin the process can be found below :

https://www.acumatica.com/partners-overview/become-an-isv-vendor/request-isv-partnership/

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but I imagine any downvotes came before your most recent edit, and given the edit greatly improves your answer, I expect the community will (given time) give support to your answer if they find that it aids them

Comment: Thanks much, Joshua.  That's more valid info than I had gotten in six years!  ;D